# Random position for submit button

Tags: html, forms

I have generated 2 random values for x and y values for the position of a submit button on a html form.

How do I apply them?

All I want is to position a submit button randomly!!

Comment: please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm stuck... I can use css to position any element but not sure how to do it randomly. Does css read php variables?

Comment: i understand that you are stuck, this is not what i asked. please post in your question what you have tried so far in order to resolve this issue...

Comment: How did you generate random numbers in HTML? You need to use Javascript to do it on the client, or a server-side programming language when you're generating the page.

Comment: I used php to generate the numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.style` attribute:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 230) + 1) + "px";
btn.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1) + "px";
```

```css
input[type='submit'] {
       position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="Button!" />
```

Comment: Where do I include these bits of code? The first in the body - <script> tags, the last in the <html> form... but the css bit in the middle? Wherever I put it I can't get the button to move around.

Comment: The first one is javascript, put it in a `<script>` -tag and place it at it the bottom of your body. The css just in your header (in a `<style>` -tag), and the bottom one in your `<form>` -tag.

Comment: Thank you again. I had the <style> in the body! Daft. Does it matter that the <script> is at the end of the <body>? Could it go anywhere in the <body>?

Comment: The `<script>` should be after your button